# How to efficiently compare every row to all other rows in a Pandas Dataframe based on different conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration, vectorization

I have a Python Pandas dataframe which consists of different columns:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dict = {'Payee Name':["John", "John", "John", "Sam", "Sam"],
        'Amount': [100, 30, 95, 30, 30],
        'Payment Method':['Cheque', 'Electronic', 'Electronic', 'Cheque', 'Electronic'], 
        'Payment Reference Number' : [1,2,3,4,5],
        'Payment Date' : ['1/1/2022', '1/2/2022', '1/3/2022', '1/4/2022','1/5/2022']
        }
 
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
df['Payment Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Payment Date'],format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

- [Payee Name] - the name of payee
- [Amount] - the payment amount
- [Payment Method] - either "Cheque" or "Electronic"
- [Payment Reference Number] - the payment number
- [Payment Date] - the date when the payment is made

Each row of the above represents one single payment entry.

The dataframe looks like this:

```
Payee Name  Amount  Payment Method  Payment Reference Number    Payment Date
0   John    100 Cheque          1                           2022-01-01
1   John    30  Electronic  2                           2022-02-01
2   John    95  Electronic  3                           2022-03-01
3   Sam 30  Cheque          4                           2022-04-01
4   Sam 30  Electronic  5                           2022-05-01
```

I want to create a report that can identify any payments with the same/similar payment amounts (+/- 10%) that were paid to the same person under different payment methods.  By doing so, I try to compare every row with all other rows in the same dataframe with the following conditions.

**Conditions when comparing two rows:**

1. Same payee
2. Different payment methods
3. The payment amount is the same or within a difference of 10%

**If the above conditions are all true, then the [Check] column will have the below message.**

1. "Yes - same amount" - if the payment amount is the same.
2. "Yes - within 10%" - if the difference in the payment amounts is 10% or less.

I have written the below codes.  It works, but the performance is slow due to iteration in a Pandas Dataframe.  It took about 7 mins to execute 1,300 rows.  In my real life datafile, it has about 200,000 rows.  So, may I ask if there are other methods that can help obtain the same result but run faster?

```
df['Check'] =  0
limit = 0.1  # to set the threshold for the payment difference

for i in df.index:
    for j in df.index:
        if df['Amount'].iloc[i] == df['Amount'].iloc[j] and df['Payee Name'].iloc[i] == df['Payee Name'].iloc[j] and df['Payment Method'].iloc[i] != df['Payment Method'].iloc[j] and i != j:
            df['Check'].iloc[i] = "Yes - same amount"
            break
        else:
            change = df['Amount'].iloc[j] / df['Amount'].iloc[i] - 1
            if change > -limit and change < limit and df['Payee Name'].iloc[i] == df['Payee Name'].iloc[j] and df['Payment Method'].iloc[i] != df['Payment Method'].iloc[j] and i != j:
                df['Check'].iloc[i] = "Yes - within 10%"
                break
```

After running the code, the result is as follows:

```
Payee Name  Amount  Payment Method  Payment Reference Number    Payment Date    Check
0   John    100 Cheque          1                  2022-01-01   Yes - within 10%
1   John    30  Electronic  2                  2022-02-01   0
2   John    95  Electronic  3                  2022-03-01   Yes - within 10%
3   Sam 30  Cheque          4                  2022-04-01   Yes - same amount
4   Sam 30  Electronic  5                  2022-05-01   Yes - same amount
```

Much appreciate any advice.

Comment: If you are working with 200000 data items, you should probably consider using a "real" database -- this sounds like a query which should take seconds at max. Also, your condition is asymmetric , e.g., 100 is less than 10% away from 111, but 111 is more than 10% away from 100.

Comment: @chtz Thanks, would definitely look into the database software.  I am fine with the asymmetric condition because I need to identify the transactions with similar payment amounts, usually caused by exchange rate differences when translating a foreign currency to a local currency, or caused by including/excluding bank charges and associated costs.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try using groupby on 'Payee Name' to break your dataframe into smaller pieces then run the inefficient code on these individually. (see [split-apply-combine](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html#) for discussion of approach). With luck you will see sufficient improvement to call it a day and move on to your next project.

See [split-apply-combine](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html#) for discussion on this use of groupby.

```py
## Original code minus payee logic and unnecessary index check.
def find_double_dippers(df):
    s_judgement = pd.Series(0, df.index)
    limit = 0.1
    
    for i in df.index:
        for j in df.index:
            if df['Amount'].loc[i] == df['Amount'].loc[j] and df['Payment Method'].loc[i] != df['Payment Method'].loc[j]:
                s_judgement.loc[i] = "Yes - same amount"
                break
            else:
                change = df['Amount'].loc[j] / df['Amount'].loc[i] - 1
                if change > -limit and change < limit and df['Payment Method'].loc[i] != df['Payment Method'].loc[j]:
                    s_judgement.loc[i] = "Yes - within 10%"
                    break

    return s_judgement # for combine portion of split-apply-combine


df['Check'] = df.groupby('Payee Name', group_keys=False).apply(find_double_dippers)
```

Comment: Thank you! I used your method, and it significantly reduced the processing time (6,000 rows for 15 seconds only).  It's the first time I learn about the split-apply-combine method.  I really appreciated your advice!

Comment: You could also check for `df['Payment Method'].loc[i] != df['Payment Method'].loc[j]` before checking the amount (in a surrounding `if`-block), since otherwise this is checked twice.

Comment: @chtz Thanks chtz for the advice! I followed your advice and the run time further reduced to 11s for 6000 rows.  That's great!